# Entering only Digits in Excel DataSheet Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, data-validation

I want users to enter only 1 or 0 in a cell column in Excel 2007. Users should not be able to enter anything else than 1 or 0. How can I do this in Excel?

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/apply-data-validation-to-cells-HP010072600.aspx) page has instructions on how to do it, [in detail](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/apply-data-validation-to-cells-HP010072600.aspx#BM4_2). I will quote a section though:

> [image: Data Validation dialog]

Answer (score 1):

Lance: You can restrict users entry using data validation. To create your data validation, follow the steps below:

- Use Sheet2 in the workbook to create the name range for the data validation
- In column A, row A1, make sure to enter a heading. For example Enter_Number
- In Sheet 1, make sure you type your heading in A1
- Highlight A2:A10, click Data on the menu option, click Data Validation, select List from the dropdown option
- In the Source filed, do = and enter your heading title in Sheet2. For example, =Number 
  You can use the F3 in the Source field to choose the heading you entered in Sheet 2
  [image: Screen Shot Detailing Data Validation Steps]
  [image]

[image]